# Split a string into subtrings based on fixed length with vim

Tags: string, vim

In most scripting languages it is easy to split a string into fixed length substrings without a delimiter. e.g. in ruby I can do

```
'acgatgctgc'.scan(/.{3}/).join(' ') #=>"acg atg ctg"
```

What is the equivalent of doing this using vim script? or achieving the same with a single command in vim?

edit
NB: notice Ruby strips the last c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
join(split('acgatgctgc','.\{3}\zs'),' ')
```

the above line will give you

```
"acg atg ctg c"
```

I know there is a `c`, it could be removed by `filter()` function, if you want to remove it:

```
join(filter(split('acgatgctgc','.\{3}\zs'),'len(v:val)==3'),' ')
```

will give you:

```
"acg atg ctg"
```

I don't know if it answers your question.

Comment: Here is the related `:substitute` command if you need it: `:%s/\v.{3}($)@!/& /g`

Comment: @kent. Ruby(2.0) seems to strip the last c! using the example code I gave.